# Fortran write inserts 2 newlines w

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-composer

In a simple test routine i am curently writing in Fortran90, the string output is longer than the screen. When using the standard write(*,*) statement, the output in the Instead of simply add a new line and continue on the next line, a second newline is added before continuing the output.

Example code:

```
write(*,*) "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

Intel Visual Fortran Composer XE 2013 SP1 output:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Why that is ? Where does this extra newline come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using *list-directed* output, which you do with the second `*` in the arguments to the `write` statement, you surrender precise control of output formatting to the whims of the compiler writers.  Seize back control with a specific format, something like `write(*,'(a128)')` (replacing 128 with whatever is appropriate for the length of string you want to write).  See what happens then.

It might amuse you to learn to use the `repeat` function for, well, repetitive strings.

Comment: This was only an example code to simplify the questions, since the underlying code of the routine was a bit too complicated for the purpose of the question.

Indeed, this was the problem. Didnt thought list-directed output could do such weird things when not controlled. I'll make sure to avoid that in the future.

Thank you !